# IIS ASP with OpenOffice - ActiveX Component Can't Create Object

Tags: iis, asp-classic, vbscript, activex

I have an old website developed in classic ASP, I need to add openoffice functionality in it, so I have created a DLL using UNO services of OpenOffice in VB. I have tried that DLL from locally using in another EXE project and even on command line project.

The problem starts when I use that DLL to ASP. It says 'ActiveX Component Can't Create Object', I have searched a lot and finally I decided to ask some experts regarding this issue. As from my searches it says there is some issue with IIS security. I need to configure some directories with some particular user rights and some DCOM service configuration, seriously I don't know anything about setting user rights to IIS and setting DCOM Services rights, below are URL that points to that issue.

http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=24400&highlight=activex+component
http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=73470
http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=26366

I think there is not such Step-By-Step post available who can direct openoffice users to configure with IIS and ASP.

Please Help, as its and urgent issue.

Thanking You,

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer by my self.

I have created a service in windows that calls star office document with administrative privileges.

Answer (score 2):

Verify if the App Pool assigned to your site or virtual directory has the "Enable 32 Bits Applications" parameter in True. Setting it to True was the solution to a similar problem a was facing some time ago.